# Is there a method or plugin to download my products in WooCommerce?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

For reasons not worth going in to, our "design team" wants to revert back to an earlier version of the site, but that would mean losing many of the products I've added or updated. Is there a way to download or export all these products so I can easily re-add them?

Comment: I think you probably want Woothemes Product CSV Import Suite  plugin.  It's 200 dollars, but probably still better than retyping the lot.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the "export" option (which I didn't know about) to sort of get what I wanted. The product descriptions were the main thing I wanted, the images I already had saved. So I'll see if this works before spending the money.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your database, simply execute and export the result of the following query :

```
SELECT sku.meta_value AS sku,
       pr.post_title AS title,
       pr.post_content AS description,
       term.name AS category,
       pr.guid AS link,
       img.guid AS image_link
FROM wp_posts pr
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON pr.ID = pm.post_id
AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta sku ON pr.ID = sku.post_id
AND sku.meta_key = '_sku'
INNER JOIN wp_posts img ON pm.meta_value = img.ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships temr ON pr.ID = temr.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy temt ON temr.term_taxonomy_id = temt.term_taxonomy_id
AND temt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
INNER JOIN wp_terms term ON temt.term_id = term.term_id
WHERE pr.post_type = 'product';
```